# Push SwifuUIscreen from AppDelegate

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can i push a SwiftUI screen from AppDelegate, e.x. when i click on a Remote notification in willPresent Method, i want the user to redirect to my TabBarView() with tab notification selected. I also need to have initialized my rootViewModel since i have logic there.

MainApp:

```
@main 
struct MainApp: App {

@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

private var rootViewModel: MainViewModel

init() {
    self.rootViewModel = MainViewModel()
}

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        if authenticated {
            Tabbar()
                .environmentObject(rootViewModel)
        } else {
            SecondScreen()
                .environmentObject(rootViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

}

AppDelegate:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("willPresent notification")
        let info = notification.request.content.userInfo
        completionHandler([.badge, .sound, .banner])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the tab selection programmatically from `AppDelegate`:

- You have to use the `TabBar` initializer that takes a `Binding` to the selected tab, and
- You have to be able to set the binding's value from `AppDelegate`.

Here's one solution.

First, define an `enum` representing the tab selection:

```
enum TabSelection: Hashable {
    case firstTab
    case secondTab
    case thirdTab
}
```

Then, make your `AppDelegate` conform to `ObservableObject` and give it a `Published` property that holds the tab selection:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, ObservableObject {
    @Published var tabSelection: TabSelection = .firstTab
}
```

Finally, update your view to use `tabSelection` to control the selected tab:

- Get a `Binding<TabSelection>` from `appDelegate`,
- pass it to the `TabView` initializer, and
- use the `tag` modifier on each tab subview.

```
struct MainApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    private var rootViewModel: MainViewModel
    
    init() {
        self.rootViewModel = MainViewModel()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if rootViewModel.authenticated {
                TabView(selection: _appDelegate.projectedValue.tabSelection) {
                    FirstTab()
                        .tag(TabSelection.firstTab)
                    SecondTab()
                        .tag(TabSelection.secondTab)
                    ThirdTab()
                        .tag(TabSelection.thirdTab)
                }
                    .environmentObject(rootViewModel)
            } else {
                SecondScreen()
                    .environmentObject(rootViewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You *should* be able to say `$appDelegate.tabSelection` to get the `Binding`. But I'm writing this answer on my iPad and the Swift Playgrounds app is complaining about `$appDelegate`, so I'm using `_appDelegate.projectedValue.tabSelection` to get the `Binding`.